# How to use Python modules for interactive scripting in Valor NPI tool

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to interact with a tool called Valor NPI using a Python script. This tool is used for designing and manufacturing electronic goods. As my first step, I ran a simple "hello world" program and it's running fine. But when I try to run some script using Python modules, it is showing a `ModuleNotFound` error. To resolve this problem, I've put the required modules and pip manually in that location (`\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\all\python`). Then, to check if it worked, I wrote a small script using the `numpy` module and tried to run it in that Valor tool. But it is showing the following error:

```
 File "C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\all\python\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\all\python\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\all\python\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/MentorGraphics/Valor/vNPI_DIR/sys/scripts/numpy1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\all\python\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\all\python\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\nv\deps\Python\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

How can I solve this? How can I use Python modules in that tool?

Comment: Did you **copy** the numpy files into the python directory or did you use `pip`? Can you execute the command `C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\nv\deps\Python\python.exe -m pip list` and add the output of it to your question?

Comment: @MSH (in case you're reading this): when trying to [edit](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30468104) a post, please make sure you understand it. In this case, most of the text is actually part of the error message and should be in the code block. Knowing that, your edit made no sense. Also, when editing, please fix obvious spelling/grammar issues as well, because your edit proposal takes time of reviewers and currently blocks the queue and prevents other edits. Please keep making edit suggestions, but take this into account so your edits will be more helpful :-)

Comment: @wovano i just copied the numpy in that python dir manually .. i didnt pip anything...and i executed the command C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\nv\deps\Python\python.exe -m pip list  **OUTPUT**Package Version
------- -------
numpy   1.21.4
pandas  1.3.4
pip     21.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Python packages are installed in different ways, usually using `pip`, sometimes using a `setup.py`, but generally not by just coping a module to your Python directory. In most cases, that won't work.

I have no experience with the Valor NPI tool, and I recommend first searching for documentation of that tool if it supports third-party Python modules. Maybe there is a recommended way of installing.

Otherwise, I think you should install the needed modules using `pip` for this specific Python installation. In your case, I would execute:

```
C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\nv\deps\Python\python.exe -m pip install numpy
```

And likewise for other packages that you need (replacing `numpy` by the corresponding module). Since you already copied `numpy` to your Python directory, you should remove that to avoid conflicts between the different copies.

Comment: @Thanks....will try this definitely...but the thing is that i copied the pip also...basically when we install the tool it creates the setup files  in the system....they newly provided support for python script...in documents they only gave an example of python scripting where for every job they r calling some .exe files....i assume these .exes' holds the libraries ....i tried to decompile these by many ways but i failed....without knowing the source code i cant make a call and write program...thats why i am trying to figure out how can we use pips as well as libraries manually..

Comment: i deleted all the manually putted library and did the same what you suggested ...its saying (Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages ) its not doing anything with the tool folders.. should i have to add the path in Environment Variables and try to install the pip and then other packages insted?

Comment: @jonsnowArnab Did you literally copy-paste the command from my answer? If not, please do so. Otherwiser it will use a Python version from your path.

Comment: @jonsnowArnab, you should also check the instructions in the Valor NPI System Management User Guide, Chapter 7 "Scripts for Automation", which you should be able to find through the Valor NPI Help menu. Or you could ask it at the Valor NPI [community site](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/topic/0TO4O000000YTxWWAW/design-for-manufacturing-optimization-valor-npi). I guess it's quite an expensive program, so you probably should have some support from the manufacturer as well.

Comment: yes i did exactly same as you suggested ....i went to the location and cmd enter  then i wrote pip install numpy..(C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\nv\deps\Python>pip install numpy) is it what you suggested?

Comment: exactly i have gone through the whole User Guide already. they provided very less info  . and I have A official account in Siemens in their i asked the same question they didn't  reply anything yet....actually python scripting support newly added in valor npi..but  the thing is that i can run simple hello world in that tool but when i am  writing using modules .....its saying it is not there ....maybe the .exes' holds the libs but if i cant see the code i cant use them r8? or is there any way to use python modules...

Comment: @jonsnowArnab, "_then i wrote pip install numpy_". No, this is **not** what I suggested. I suggested to copy the **full** command line (this one: `C:\MentorGraphics\Valor\vNPI_114\edir\nv\deps\Python\python.exe -m pip install numpy`), and pasting exactly that WITHOUT ANY MODIFICATIONS in a cmd terminal. But maybe it's better to wait for an answer from Siemens. Sorry, but I don't have time to walk you through it step by step. I hope my answer and comments at least put you in the right direction and you will get it working.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it could not find `_multiarray_umath.cp310-win_amd64.pyd` under your `numpy/core` folder.

Like @wovano, I suggest you install the module through pip instead of copying the module folder. Sometimes it can work, sometimes will not.

You can follow these steps:

1. In the terminal create a virtual environment through the command of
   `python -m venv .venv`
2. use the `Python: Select Interpreter` command from the Command Palette
   (Ctrl+Shift+P) to select the virtual environment `.venv`
3. Create a new terminal(**Ctrl+Shift+`**) that will activate the `.venv` virtual environment automatically
4. install the NumPy with the command of `pip install numpy`

You can refer to this [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment) for the detailed steps.

Comment: But OP is not using VS Code, but trying to integrate Python scripts in an external tool. So I do not expect a virtual environment to work. It seems like the tool includes and uses its own Python interpreter (so basically also an isolated environment).